# Get one Subscription from two Subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to setup just one subscription from these two subscriptions

```
this.dfs.mainProductQuery('data').pipe(
        map((items) => {
          this.arrayItems = items;
        })).subscribe();
this.cj.getData().pipe(
          map((val, i) => {
            return val;
        })).subscribe();
```

The mainProduct() return 25 records that contains an ID.
The getData() returns 1,000 records. I want to get only one subscription with data from both and match them up by id. The ids in each are the same.

I attempted to add

```
this.products = combineLatest(this.affProducts, this.dogfoods);
```

But the this.affProducts is erroring saying {} is not assignable to Subscribe

Comment: Please include sample input and expected output.

Comment: Post your JSON also

Comment: "Please help! Also, here is my code, here is my data, here is what I've tried, etc."

Comment: I added more info can you remove the negative please

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but have you tried the assign function. So something like this:

{`let combined = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);`}

what that would do is combine the two objects but any matches, it would take the first instance of any key that happens to be there.

Comment: So i tried that and it does join the objects together; however i need to get both objects that match the particular UPC Id first before getting the results.

Comment: hmmm.. can you push each object that matches that particular UPC into its own array and then assign each object in that array to make a consolidated object?

Comment: So the getData has a list of all products and the mainproductquery on has a subset of products with UPC.  So I have to figure out how to match the two first the push an array. Not sure how to do it any other way